# PySpark replace less frequent items with most frequent items

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a categorical column in a data frame which has some levels, and now I would like to replace those less frequent levels (which have frequencies in terms of percentage of total less than a specified percentage) with the most frequent level. How would I realize that in an elegant and compact way?

Below is an example, if I set the specified frequency as 0.3, then level "c" should be replaced by level "a" since it's frequency is only 1/6 which is below 0.3.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("foo")

df = sc.parallelize([ row("a"), row("b"), row("c"), row("a"), row("a"), row("b") ]).toDF()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

#sample data
row = Row("foo")
df = sc.parallelize([ row("a"), row("b"), row("c"), row("a"), row("a"), row("b") ]).toDF()

df_temp = df.groupBy('foo').agg((f.count(f.lit(1))/df.count()).alias("frequency"))
most_frequent_foo = df_temp.sort(f.col('frequency').desc()).select('foo').first()[0]
df_temp = df_temp.withColumn('foo_replaced',
                             f.when(f.col("frequency") < 0.3, f.lit(most_frequent_foo)).otherwise(f.col('foo')))

df_final = df.join(df_temp, df.foo==df_temp.foo, 'left').drop(df_temp.foo).drop("frequency")
df_final.show()
```

Output is:

```
+---+------------+
|foo|foo_replaced|
+---+------------+
|  c|           a|
|  b|           b|
|  b|           b|
|  a|           a|
|  a|           a|
|  a|           a|
+---+------------+
```